# SB3 AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor and AuthorizationManager<MethodInvocation> is not kicking in unit testing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

`hi All, we have migrated to SB3 and have made changes to adopt new method security.`
`I below bean initialization:`

`@AutoConfiguration`
`@EnableMethodSecurity`
`@Import(value = { CustomConfig.class})`
`public class MethodInterceptorConfiguration {`

```
@Autowired
private Environment springEnvironment;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

@Bean
public RoleExpressionRegistry getRoleExpressionRegistry() {
DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler =
new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
expressionHandler.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
return new RoleExpressionRegistry(expressionHandler);
}

@Bean
public AuthorizationManager<MethodInvocation> authorizationManager(AnnotationSecurityService        annotationSecurityService , RoleExpressionRegistry roleExpressionRegistry) {
return new CustomMethodSecurityManager(annotationSecurityService ,          springEnvironment,roleExpressionRegistry);
}

```
@Bean
public AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor      authorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterception(AuthorizationManager\<MethodInvocation\> authorizationManager) {
 return new      AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor(RolePointCut.forAllAnnotations(),authorizationManager);
}
```

`}`

`Note: here AnnotationSecurityService  is coming from CustomConfig.class.`
`RolePointCut: provides list of annotations for which to do the pointcut`

**`PROBLEM:`**  `while executing the SB3 application; its all working fine and I could see method interceptor is invoking for all the list of annotations given in RolePointCut.`
`But its not executing in test enviornment.`

`Thanks in Advance!`

`I have been testing with below test class:`

```
`@SpringJUnitConfig({ CutomCommand.Handler.class, MethodInterceptorConfiguration.class`
`})`
`class CommandTest {`

  @Autowired
  CustomCommandHandler handler;

 `@Test`
 `@WithMockUser(authorities = "TestRole")`
 `void test_unauthorized_role() {`
`assertThrows(CustomAccessException.class, () -> handler.execute(new            CutomCommand())));`
`}`
```

`}`

`}`

`NOTE: here CutomCommand.execute() method gets executed in above testcase. and this method dosen't have the TestRole applied to it.`
`here I was expecting MethodInterceptor to kick in, but the cursor can directly go inside CutomCommand.execute() without checking any Roles.`

Just for Reference:

```
@Value
@ToString
public class CustomCommand extends Command<XXX> {


    @Service
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Slf4j
    static class Handler implements SomeHandler<CustomCommand, XXX> {

        @Override
        @SOMERole
        public XXX  execute(CustomCommand cmd) {
           return xxx;  
    }
    
}
}
```

`Please can you suggest what could be wrong in my test cases.`

Comment: just to put more info, while starting application, SB is loading org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext, 
and in testing its loading org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext